# Kaspresso. How type text in webView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-espresso, kakao

I need type text in WebView in this editView

[image]

I try  get input field like this:

```
val numberCard = UiEditText {
        withId("", "pan")
    }
```

But get error `com.kaspersky.components.kautomator.intercept.exception.UnfoundedUiObjectException: The UiObject2 was not found on the screen. The selector=BySelector [RES='\Q:id/pan\E'], index=0`
I can get label by text like this

```
val numberCard = UiEditText {
        withText("text_label")
    }
```

But type text not work for this

I also try use onWebView like this

```
        onWebView()
            .forceJavascriptEnabled()
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "pan"))
            .perform(webClick())
        device.keyboard.typeText("555")
```

But device.keyboard.typeText return error com.kaspersky.kaspresso.internal.exceptions.AdbServerException:
AdbServer. The command=input text 5 was performed with timeout exception.